# getting resource #id 3 error

Tags: php

When I run this am getting resource #id 3 result. Please look into my code and help me solving this... Please

```
<form method="post" action="search.php" name="search_form" onsubmit="return checkCheckBoxes(this);">

         <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="qwerty_keypad" id="search1">QWERTY Keypad<br /><br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="touch_screen" id="search2"> Touch Screen<br /><br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="usb" id="search3"> 
         USB Drive<br /><br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="mobile_tracker" id="search4">Mobile Tracker<br /><br />
         <input type="checkbox" name="search[]" value="Backup" id="search5">Phone backup on MMC<br /><br />
         <input type="submit" value="Search" />         </form>
```

search.php

```
<?

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="user"; // Mysql username 
$password="password"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mydb"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="mobile_search"; // Table name

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");


foreach($_POST['search'] as $search){
    $where[]= "model = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'";
}

$query = "Select model from $tbl_name where ".implode(' OR ',$where);

$result = mysql_query($query);
 echo $result;

?>
```

Comment: hahahah
My dear this is not the error.. This means that your query has been executed. Now grab the data from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read this

> mysql_qery()

function will return only resource id
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

you need to use `mysql_fetch_array` to retrieve data

Comment: foreach($_POST['search'] as $search){
    $where[]= "model = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'";
}

$query = "Select model from $tbl_name where ".implode(' OR ',$where);

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   print_r($row);
}

?> s this right?

Comment: please let me know whether am doing it properly or not. coz am getting any result

Comment: am not able to print the data. where is the mistake? please help me

Comment: yes it's right check you **select query** is this selects any thing

Comment: i think this is the problem **"Select model from ".$tbl_name." where ".implode(' OR ',$where)** let me know !

Comment: $query = "Select model from $tbl_name where ".implode(' OR ',$where);

Comment: i checked in the database too, it looks proper. there is a column name model.

Comment: print_r($row)  what it returns... replace print_r  by  extract($row);
  echo $model; what you got ?

Comment: are you sure your getting inside while loop.. i think you getting Resource id #3  from **echo $result;** .. please echo "hi"; inside loop. and try this  **mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())** if you get error .you need to correct your query. let me know

Comment: foreach($_POST['search'] as $search){
    $where[]= "model = '".mysql_real_escape_string($search)."'";
}

$query = "Select * from ".$tbl_name." where ".implode(' OR ',$where);

$result = mysql_query($query);

echo $result;

while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{


   extract($row);
   echo $model; 
   echo "hi";
   
}

?>
same thing Resource id #3

Comment: and i tried this 
$query = "Select * from ".$tbl_name." where ".implode(' OR ',$where);
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query($query);

now its giving Resource id #4

Comment: please follow me . then only i can help you.did you get **hi**  and did you use **or die(mysql_error())**

Comment: @ gowri. Yes i tried putting hi inside the while loop but again it says Resource id #3.
When i use or die(mysql_error()) it gives me Resource id #4
Let me know am am putting it in a right place.

Comment: so your not inside loop.your getting Resource id from **echo $result;**  remove this echo...and try this  $query = "Select * from ".$tbl_name." where ".implode(' OR ',$where); 
 // echo $query;  .. put the result directly to mysql and getting what ?
 
 $result = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_query());
 
  echo mysql_num_rows($result); // what this returns 
  while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  extract($row); 
  echo $model; 
  echo "hi";
   }

Comment: Hi Gowri, 
I have corrected the file as you said. now am getting the result 

Select model from mobile_search where model = 'QWERTY keypad' OR model = 'Touch Screen'0
Even after telling am i doing any mistakes? Do you want me to send the code what all i have changed?

Comment: i think your query selects **0 rows** mysql_num_rows($result);. which means your query selects nothing or it has error .. ok..so you can solve this yourself !

Comment: It should not. Coz, data is there. where i am doing wrong then? Thank you very much for your time. Where do i correct no?

Comment: hello friend i'm 100 % sure your select query selects nothing ...even you have records in table .. test your query directly in MySQL

Answer (score 4):

The is not an error that is mysql result resource id. you have to fetch the result from it.

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   print_r($row)// will give complete row
}
```

Comment: Hi Shakti,
where shud i put this while? echoing result is not needed right?